# How to share a method from parent to child component with arguments

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, methods, arguments

login.component.html

```
 <form class="login-form" name="login-form" #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="checkLogin(loginForm)">

        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="userId" [(ngModel)]="userModel.userId" #userId="ngModel" required />

        <input type="password" name="userPwd" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="userModel.userPwd" #userPwd="ngModel" required
        />
    </form>
```

login.component.ts

```
 checkLogin(loginForm) {

        let loginFormData = loginForm.value;

        this.sessionTime = Date.now();
        loginFormData.sessionTime = this.sessionTime;
        ...
        ...
        ...

    }
```

admin.component.ts

```
 export class AdminComponent implements OnInit{
      @ViewChild(LoginComponent) child: LoginComponent;

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.child.checkLogin()); //as agruments is not passed am getting error 
      }
```

If i pass argument saying checkLogin(form: LoginForm) getting errors
But in the above way i can share data from one component to another component tried with sharing sample text.Problem is with sharing method with arguments.
Can anyone help me with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loginForm as a public field of your controller.
In this way, your method checkLogin won't take any params and you can call it without errors.